# Powershell scripts to determine remote CPU Temperature

Tags: powershell-v4.0

Is there a Powershell Script to remotely check the CPU temperature of a Domain PC.
Thanks

Comment: Why would you only care about the CPU temperature when there are other components?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of a ready-to-use script for that purpose. But a good starting point I used in the past might be

```
get-wmiobject MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -namespace "root/wmi"
```

which would query the temperature information via WMI.

Be aware though, this approach does not work on any hardware but is dependend on the Mainboard make and model.